# Script C# in SSIS to manipulate an excel sheet

Tags: c#, vba, ssis

I'm trying to create an script C# in SSIS to create a new column in a sheet on Excel.

I need to know the IndentLevel of a cell in excel and for this i have to create a new column with this values.

I'm trying to do this (Script in c#):

```
Range values = sheet.get_Range("A13");
values.Value = sheet.Range["B13"].IndentLevel();
```

In VBA Works like this (Script in VBA inside of a excell):

```
Range("A16").Value = Range("B16").IndentLevel
```

In C# how can i do that? i'm trying everything but doenst work.

Complete script:

```
            xlApp = new _Excel.Application();
            xlApp.Visible = true;
            oWB = (_Excel.Workbook)xlApp.Workbooks.Open(destFile);
            _Excel.Worksheet sheet = (_Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets[1];
            sheet.Columns["B:N"].Delete();


            Range values = sheet.get_Range("A13");
            values.Value = sheet.Range["B13"].IndentLevel();
```

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying to manipulate a spreadsheet or read it in to a database?

Comment: @KeithL im trying to create a new column in an sheet of excel to insert this into a database later

Comment: I could help you read it, but I don't have any experience manipulating Excel. Do you have Excel in the environment that SSIS lives?

Comment: You also have the option of using VB.net if you already figured out that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting rid of the parenthesis seems to do the task correctly.

```
            string destFile = @"E:\StackOverflow\Sample.xlsx";

            var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlApp.Visible = true;

            var oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)xlApp.Workbooks.Open(destFile);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets[1];

            sheet.Range["A16"].Value = sheet.Range["B16"].IndentLevel;
```

The value in cell A16 is set to B16's indent level.

The only other note is to make sure that the file isn't open elsewhere, otherwise the code will open up a read-only copy.